# 7 - Posting www links without http prefix

Tags: 7

I have a simple body field that uses an input format with only "Limit allowed HTML tags".

If I enter a link ... say `<a href="www.google.com">Test</a>`
The node will transform the link's href to read `http://www.mydomain.com/www.google.com`

If I enter `<a href="http://www.google.com">Test</a>`, it will work as expected.

Is there a reason why not including http:// causes this? Is there a way around it?

I was hoping [Pathologic](http://drupal.org/project/pathologic) would solve this but it doesn't seem to have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `href="www.google.com"` really **is** `http://yourdomainandpath/www.google.com` just as `href="hello.htm"` would be as well.

Comment: Ah. This seems to apply at the browser level.